# Alert after like

Tags: javascript, facebook, alert, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

This is my script to like my facebook page on my website.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/#!/ConcessionnaireCaronMazda" data-width="300" data-height="100" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

How can i make an alert when the button is clicked ??

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`FB.Event.subscribe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to subscribe to `edge.create` event (it's working for HTML5 and XFBML versions of [Like Box Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(pageURL){
  alert('User liked page: ' + pageURL);
});
```

**NOTE:** you can use `FB.Event.subscribe` only then [Facebook JS-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) is fully loaded on page, to ensure it's loaded you may use `window.fbAsyncInit` function:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // Here Facebook JS-SDK is loaded and you may use it.
  // FB.init call should be placed here if you use it...
  // Otherwise you should use next JS-SDK URL
  // `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APPLICATION_ID`

  // Subscribe to event
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(pageURL){
    alert('User liked page: ' + pageURL);
  });
}
```

**Update:**

Just double checked and it seems that you required to use application to be able to subscribe to events and you only may do so on URL's that are within your Site/Canvas URL, otherwise next error will be thrown:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Application configuration. It must match one of the Connect or Canvas URLs or domain must be the same as or a subdomain of one of the Application's base domains.

Comment: This dont work :S or i dont understand :( Can you make me full exemple ?

Comment: @FrancoisDulude, I've updated my answer to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to use the XFMBL version then you can use the FB.Event.subscribe method, edge.create.

Like Box documentation - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

FB.Event.subscribe - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

</script>

<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/#!/ConcessionnaireCaronMazda" width="292" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>